# XCOM IronMan game break - how do I get out?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm about 2 months into an IronMan game of XCOM on PC, and I hit what appears to be a game-breaking bug. I entered an Alien Abduction mission, and I don't have sight from any of my squad members. I can't actually see their models, but I can see the UI indicating where they are. I can't tell them to move anywhere, though I can put them on Overwatch (which doesn't help).

[image]

In short, I'm stuck.

I do have the option of aborting the mission from the ESC menu, but I'm not sure what Bad Things that will entail on IronMan.

Is there a way to fix this situation? Alternatively, if I abort, will I be able to get back in without penalty?

Comment: if you do abort you'll probably cause some panic, but that's better than being stuck.  Try to quit your game first and see if you can continue it from the previous save point

Comment: I agree with Spartacus - do NOT abort. IF you abort - you'll lose all your soliders, fail the mission, and probably be 'game over'. I suggest pressing ALT-F4, or even just turning off your computer. Then turn it on and see what happens - you might actually still be in 'intercept' mode before the mission starts

Comment: Tried restarting game and PC, no dice. It's IronMan so there are no previous saves available and every decision is permanent (like aborting).

Comment: well, what you should have done is powered off the computer while the game was running. If you actually quit the game properly through the menu then the save was updated with the current stuck state, but if you had powered off it might have rolled back to wherever it last saved. But then again it might have also destroyed your save entirely.

Comment: try the scroll wheel, just in case it's a view level, and they are under a structure. I had a UFO mission where the view kept switching to looking at the top of the UFO, instead of looking at the squad. kept having to scroll down on every move, but I was able to finish the mission. everything went back to normal after that

Comment: Before aborting I would try to end your turn with the backspace key to see if it might fix itself. I doubt it would work, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I would try keeping the file from your IronMan save in its current state and save it somewhere safe on your filesystem.

This way you could go on trying to move your soldiers, abort mission, or anything that might fix the issue, without fear of nuking your progress.

Would have posted as comment if I could.